# LINQ-For-Javascript Nested Arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, linq

The [Linq-For-Javascript](http://linqjs.codeplex.com/) library contains functions that convert between "`jQuery objects`" and "`Enumerable objects`":  toEnumerable() and TojQuery(). Consider the difference between these two lines:

```
$('tr'); // returns array of tr
$('tr').toEnumerable().TojQuery(); // returns array of tr[1]
```

Converting from jQuery to Enumerable and back to jQuery does not give you what you started with. The end result is an array of arrays of elements, with each sub-array having a length of 1. I do need to make use of Enumerable, so this is just a convenient example of my problem.

This means that to get the id of an element, you'd need to do the following:

```
$('tr')[0].id; // returns "myID"
$('tr').toEnumerable().TojQuery()[0][0].id; // returns "myID"
```

I'm surprised of this, because even though I've allegedly gone back `TojQuery()`, the object returned by `TojQuery()` does not work with typical jQuery calls:

```
$('tr').find('td').length; // returns 170 (in my case)
$('tr').toEnumerable().TojQuery().find('td').length; // returns 0 (BAD)
```

I would like it if both lines returned 170, but apparently Linq-For-Javascript doesn't work that way.

So, my **questions**:

1. Why is this?
2. Am I doing it wrong?
3. If not, any good workarounds? (convert `array of 1-element arrays` to `array of elements`?)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

JQuery handles operations according to types. In the first line of the code, if finds all HTML TR objects and by the help of this information it can attach necessary functions to the found objects.

```
$('tr').find('td')
```

However, it could not understand after you change it to enumarable object since it is no longer seems to be a HTML Object instead it becomes any other type of object. Thus, jquery cannot attach a function to it.

```
$('tr').toEnumerable()
```